# fragments do not appear when I click on the menus

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i have this navigation menu and a fragment for each icon, but they don't show up

[image]

this is the code of the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_nav"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottomNav"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:padding="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

and this is from MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var bottomNav : BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadFragment(HomeFragment())
        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav) as BottomNavigationView
        bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.home -> {
                    loadFragment(HomeFragment())
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.dictionary -> {
                    loadFragment(DictionaryFragment())
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.settings -> {
                    loadFragment(SettingsFragment())
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                else -> return@setOnItemSelectedListener false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

this is the fragment_home.xml for example

[image]

this is what is supposed to happen

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is in the layout of **activity_main.xml** please find details of required modifications

1. Modify the below statement in `<LinearLayout/>` tag
   from `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_content"` to take full height of activity layout
2. Modify attribute of `<FrameLayout/>` tag to fill all the remaining height in parent `<LinearLayout/>` using the below modification

   ```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   ```

**Final xml for reference after modifications**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:padding="8dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_nav"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />



    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

check for more info about different types of layouts and UI:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout

Comment: thank you so much, it worked
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9yNP.png
do you know how to remove that purple thing and the white "circle" around the icon?